# How to do popup what will be visible when no TCP connection is established and closes after it connects?

Tags: flutter

I'm totally new to flutter.
I need to do a simple app that fetches a few data from a device over wifi (the device acts as AP).
I want to have some popup shown, when the device is not connected, that will show "not connected" and have a button to open wifi settings (just call it from app_settings)
And it shall close this popup when the connection is established.
I think I will reuse requests that were used for AJAX, so just a simple web request with a plaintext response of a few numbers.
The target device is on fixed IP on its own network. So I do not need any more detection than just sending a request and seeing if it returns.
And when that connection is successful, I want to fetch that data a few times a second if possible.

Comment: For better help show what you have tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package called [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) that checks your connectivity.
Usage:

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
}
```

If you'd like to make a call to a web service request consider using the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package with a `timeout()` to check if the service is available.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("myurl.com/MyService")).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 4));
```

If **after 4 seconds** the function did not return anything (or complete), it will throw a [TimeoutException](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-async/TimeoutException-class.html), or you can specify what to do as a parameter.

Read more here > [Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-async/Future/timeout.html)